# How Can I transform a array of char's in a string in C++?

Tags: c++

I have

```
char array[5] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'}
```

I would be

```
string text = "test"
```

I can't use any function of string.h to make this proccess.

Comment: `<string.h>` is a C header for C-style strings, it is deprecated in C++. In C++ you `#include <string>` instead. This will enable C++ string objects, such as `std::string`.

Comment: `array` **is** a string. It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
const int size = 4;
string text = "";
char array[size] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};

for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
   text+=array[i];
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a non-const size for an array. This example is ill-formed.

Comment: I think it's okay. It runs successfully in both cases, putting `const size` or not.

Comment: It only works if you use language extensions. It's not OK in standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

There's a constructor for that.

```
std::string text(array);
```